# AngularJS: open new window and maintain two-way data binding

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm looking to open a new browser window with angular `$scope` data inside:

```
<div ng-app="test" ng-controller="testController">
<input type="text" ng-model="var" />
    <button ng-click="openWindow()">push!</button>
</div>

var test = angular.module('test', []);

test.controller('testController', ['$compile', '$scope','$window', function($compile, $scope, $window) {
    $scope.var = 'hello'
    $scope.openWindow = function() {
        $scope.window = $window.open('', '_blank', 'width=500,height=400');
        angular.element($scope.window.document.body).append($compile($scope.var)($scope));
    };
}]);
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/d8atdw0t/55/)

The above doesn't return any data in the window. It works as a directive like [in here](http://blog-softnauts2.rhcloud.com/2014/03/18/building-angular-directive-that-shows-content-in-new-window/).

If I `append('hello world')` it works. Can someone show me how to bind the data correctly without the use of a directive, if that's even possible?

Comment: try reading errors in console.You have no reference to new window and code in fiddle is different than code in question

Comment: @charlietfl apologies - fiddle is updated

Comment: try this ... http://jsfiddle.net/d8atdw0t/56/ For more advanced html just pull out the html needed to string after you compile it

Comment: @charlietfl thanks - I need it also to maintain two-way data binding. I suspect scope is the issue but I can't see how.

Comment: use postMessage API events to update across the windows. You won't have any events available inside the new window unless you create them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can *append* to body compiled element with binding, something like

```
$compile('<div>{{var}}</div>')($scope)
```

or you can add html to body itself and compile it

```
$compile(angular.element($scope.window.document.body).html('{{var}}'))($scope);
```

[Sample JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/d8atdw0t/57/)